# When describing a ratio, should 'between' or 'of' be used?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

When describing a ratio, should *ratio between* or *ratio of* be used? Example:

The ratio ***between*** floor area of smallest rectangle ***to*** the enclosed contour area of a polygon is tested with a defined threshold.

The ratio ***of***  smallest rectangle's floor area ***to*** the enclosed contour area of a polygon is tested with a defined threshold.

Answer (score 13):

The correct usage would be with **of-to** instead of *between-to*. Instead of *between-to*, you should use *between-and* but even after that, the more correct usage will be **of-to**.

> The ratio *between* floor area of smallest rectangle and the enclosed contour area of a polygon is tested with a defined threshold.

Also, from the text on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology) about the [notation and terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio#Notation_and_terminology) of ratios

> The ratio of numbers A and B can be expressed as:
>
> 1. The ratio **of** A **to** B
> 2. A is to B
> 3. A:B
> 4. A fraction (rational number) that is the quotient of A divided by B

Comment: It's worth noting that #4 is a formal definition. You'd see that written in a textbook, or hear that in that in a classroom, but that's not how people talk in everyday conversation. The _between-and_ construct you mention is less formal, but maybe more apt for less formal speech: _The ratio between girls and boys in the drama club is about 4 to 1._

Comment: And there again, we use the `to` for representing ratios. @J.R. AFAR, I was explicitly taught(in school time) to use **to** when referring to ratios.

Comment: Yes, the ratio itself uses `to`, but the form _The ratio **between** A **and** B is X **to** Y_ is not uncommon. Also, when you said you were taught to use "to", now I'm curious – was that in math class, or in English class? (It's not uncommon for something to be common conversationally, but considered erroneous mathematically, such as, "There are an infinite number of them." My math teacher would say, "There are _infinitely many_ of them," and aver those are **not** the same thing, but my English teacher might ask, "Don't those mean the same?").

Comment: @J.R. It was more like my father told me. =) Times like this, and I'm proud that I had my parents as a teacher :P

Answer (score 4):

Generally I would use the pairs *between* / *and* and *of* / *to*, as shown below:

> BMI is the ratio **of** someone's weight **to** their height.
>
> BMI is the ratio **between** someone's weight **and** their height.

Both have the same meaning, and are otherwise interchangable.